# Developer Story required from-to dates for Open Source Project

Tags: support, developer-story, help-center

I am getting stories in the wrong positions because of the date.

As per below Image:
I have added a new story (you can see the image right part) of the Medium blog link with yesterday's date. Now Its displaying story on 5th position which should be displayed on the 1st position.

I have tried to change the date of other stories (as you can see in the image)

[image]

My question is:

- Why Open Source Project required **End Date**
- Its displaying top side If I select **current**.

What to do If I want to show recently added stories on top?

Comment: still under [status-review].